# Akka Actors send message to concrete actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

Using Akka actors is it possible to organize actors into a ring and send messages to only two (left, right) neighbors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the actors have `ActorRef`s for their left-and-right neighbors, it's definitely possible to organize them into a ring.

Note you'd have to have a protocol for the actors to be told who their neighbors are  (as all actors except the last one in the ring would have a neighbor who hadn't been spawned when that actor spawned (so setting the neighbors via `Props` wouldn't work)).